# Pros and Cons of Fluent and XML Configuration

Tags: configuration-management, fluent-interface, xml-configuration

If you we're about to start a new project with some third party libraries (logging, orm, di, whatever), would you prefer to configure all this libraries via programming with fluent interfaces or with XML files?

Would you use a library that only supports one of these options (Fluent or XML)? Or do you prefer libraries that gives you the possibility to choose between a variety of configuration strategies.

For those who like code, take this as a hypothetical example (written in C#).

This is Fluent Configuration:

```
LogConfiguration.ConfigureStorage()
   .ForDatabase("CommonDB")
     .AsMsSqlDatabase()
     .WithConnectionString("server=(local); database=Northwind; Integrated Security=true;")
     .AsDefault();
```

This is XML Configuration:

```
<logging>
    <database name="CommonDB" provider="MSSQL" connString="server=(local); database=Northwind; Integrated Security=true;" default="true" />
</logging>
```

Finally, what are the Pros and Cons of Fluent and XML Configuration?

Until now, we've come to this:

**Fluent Configuration in Code**

**Pros**

- Strongly typed evaluated by compiler
- Conditional configuration

**Cons**

- Unabled reconfigured after build

**XML Configuration**

**Pros**

- Ability to easily change after deploy

**Cons**

- XML is verbose
- More vulnerable to typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use xml for attributes I might want to change post-build (such as connection strings, loggers)

I prefer strongly typed (compiled) fluent configuration in code for things such as NHibernate mappings that only change during development.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly by fluent you mean in code? If so, then definitely I'd choose XML. If by fluent you meant pure text files, then still I'd choose XML.
Pros:

- readability
- self documenting tags (of course if you create those ;) )

Cons:

- file length, but I wouldn't bother that

Currently all my projects are XML based.

Comment: You can have the same (or even better) readability with configuration in the code, take as an example the difference between FluentNHibernate and the .hbm.xml files. In this case I find Fluent way easier to understand.

Comment: In the example author mentioned something important -> DB configuration. In that case definitely XML is better approach. Whereas hibernate entity configuration, I also place in the source code. The question is what the author really meant? Which part of the configuration?

Comment: I am the author :) My comment on your answer was about readability and not maintainability. When talking about changing configuration after deploy (like Connection String), I also agree that XML is better.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your username ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that XML configs may be less verbose and even simpler than Java configs.

Look on my comparison of [the same config on XML and on Java DSL in Spring Integrations's `wireTap` config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663452/wiretap-configuration-in-spring-integration-java-dsl)

Also XML configs may be more familiar to less experienced programmers. So efforts for maintain such configs in the future may be less.